# Compile-time polymorphism and run-time polymorphism

Tags: c++

I noticed that somewhere polymorphism just refer to virtual function. However, somewhere they include the function overloading and template. Later, I found there are two terms, compile time polymorphism and run-time polymorphism. Is that true?

My question is when we talked about polymorphism generally, what's the widely accepted meaning?

Comment: http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/1015511

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you're right, in C++ there are two recognized "types" of polymorphism. And they mean pretty much what you think they mean

## Dynamic polymorphism

is what C#/Java/OOP people typically refer to simply as "polymorphism". It is essentially subclassing, either deriving from a base class and overriding one or more virtual functions, or implementing an interface. (which in C++ is done by overriding the virtual functions belonging to the abstract base class)

## Static polymorphism

takes place at compile-time, and could be considered a variation of ducktyping. The idea here is simply that different types can be used in a function to represent the same concept, despite being completely unrelated. For a very simple example, consider this

```
template <typename T>
T add(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) { return lhs + rhs; }
```

If this had been dynamic polymorphism, then we would define the `add` function to take some kind of "IAddable" object as its arguments. Any object that implement that interface (or derive from that base class) can be used despite their different implementations, which gives us the polymorphic behavior. We don't care which type is passed to us, as long as it implements some kind of "can be added together" interface.
However, the compiler doesn't actually *know* which type is passed to the function. The exact type is only known at runtime, hence this is *dynamic* polymorphism.

Here, though, we don't require you to derive from anything, the type `T` just has to define the  `+` operator. It is then inserted *statically*. So at compile-time, we can switch between any valid type as long as they *behave* the same (meaning that they define the members we need)

This is another form of polymorphism. In principle, the effect is the same: The function works with any implementation of the concept we're interested in. We don't care if the object we work on is a string, an int, a float or a complex number, as long as it implements the "can be added together" *concept*.

Since the type used is known statically (at compile-time), this is known as static polymorphism. And the way static polymorphism is achieved is through templates and function overloading.

However, when a C++ programmer  *just* say polymorphism, they generally refer to dynamic/runtime polymorphism.

(Note that this isn't necessarily true for all languages. A functional programmer will typically mean something like static polymorphism when he uses the term -- the ability to define generic functions using some kind of parametrized types, similar to templates)

Answer (score 10):

"Polymorphism" literally means "many forms". The term is unfortunately a bit overloaded in computer science (excuse the pun).

According to [FOLDOC](http://foldoc.org/polymorphism), polymorphism is "a concept first identified by Christopher Strachey (1967) and developed by Hindley and Milner, allowing types such as list of anything."

In general, it's "a programming language feature that allows values of different data types to be handled using a uniform interface", to quote [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_polymorphism), which goes on to describe two main types of polymorphism:

**Parametric** polymorphism is when the *same code* can be applied to multiple data types. Most people in the object-oriented programming community refer to this as "generic programming" rather than polymorphism.  Generics (and to some extent templates) fit into this category.

**Ad-hoc** polymorphism is when *different code* is used for different data-types.  Overloading falls into this category, as does overriding.  This is what people in the object-oriented community are generally referring to when they say "polymorphism". (and in fact, many mean overriding, not overloading, when they use the term "polymorphism")

For ad-hoc polymorphism there's also the question of whether the resolution of implementation code happens at run-time (dynamic) or compile-time (static). Method overloading is generally static, and method overriding is dynamic. This is where the terms **static/compile-time polymorphism** and **dynamic/run-time polymorphism** come from.

Answer (score 5):

Usually people are referring to run-time polymorpism in my experience ...

Answer (score 5):

When a C++ programmer says "polymorphism" he most likely means subtype polymorphism, which means "late binding" or "dynamic binding" with virtual functions.  Function overloading and generic programming are both instances of polymorphism and they do involve static binding at compile time, so they can be referred to collectively as compile-time polymorphism.  Subtype polymorphism is almost always referred to as just polymorphism, but the term could also refer to all of the above.

Answer (score 4):

In its most succinct form, polymorphism means the ability of one type to appear as if it is another type.

There are two main types of polymorphism.

1. Subtype polymorphism: if `D` derives from `B` then `D` is a `B`.
2. Interface polymorphism: if `C` implements an interface `I`.

The first is what you are thinking of as runtime polymorphism. The second does not really apply to C++ and is a really a concept that applies to Java and C#.

Some people do think of overloading in the special case of operators (`+`, `-`, `/`, `*`) as a type of polymorphism because it allows you to think of types that have overloaded these operators as replaceable for each other (i.e., `+` for `string` and `+` for `int`). This concept of polymorphism most often applies to dynamic languages. I consider this an abuse of the terminology.

As for template programming, you will see some use the term "polymorphism" but this is really a very different thing than what we usually mean by polymorphism. A better name for this concept is "generic programming" or "genericity."

Comment: Way to dodge the question. ;)

Comment: Your second type is just a special case of the first type. If C implements I then the type C is derived from I. In C++ you can get pretty much the same effect as a Java or C# interface by creating a class with only "pure virtual" methods.

Comment: Downvoting because it doesn't answer the question. You have described similar variants of dynamic polymorphism. You haven't given any indication that you're even aware of what static polymorphism *is*.

Comment: @jalf: See my last paragraph.

Comment: Yep, it's wrong. :) It's a different thing than what people indoctrinated with Java mean by polymorphism, but the word has a long history being used to describe this in functional languages. OOP doesn't have a monopoly on the truth, you know. :)

Answer (score 1):

Various types of Function overloading (compile time polymorphism ...
9 Jun 2011 ... Polymorphism means same entity behaving differently at different times. Compile time polymorphism is also called as static binding.
http://churmura.com/technology/programming/various-types-of-function-overloading-compile-time-polymorphism-static-binding/39886/

Answer (score 1):

A simple explanation on compile time polymorphism and run time polymorphism from :
[questionscompiled.com](http://questionscompiled.com/answer.jsp?technology=cpp&qid=148)

Compile time Polymorphism:

C++ support polymorphism. One function multiple purpose, or in short many functions having same name but with different function body.
For every function call compiler binds the call to one function definition at compile time. This decision of binding among several functions is taken by considering formal arguments of the function, their data type and their sequence.

Run time polymorphism:

C++ allows binding to be delayed till run time. When you have a function with same name, equal number of arguments and same data type in same sequence in base class as well derived class and a function call of form: base_class_type_ptr->member_function(args); will always call base class member function. The keyword virtual on a member function in base class indicates to the compiler to delay the binding till run time.

Every class with atleast one virtual function has a vtable that helps in binding at run time. Looking at the content of base class type pointer it will correctly call the member function of one of possible derived / base class member function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are basically right. Compile-time polymorphism is the use of templates (instances of which's types vary, but are fixed at compile time) whereas run-time polymorphism refers to the use of inheritance and virtual functions (instances of which's types vary and are fixed at run time).

Comment: Using "polymorphism" to apply to template programming and "polymorphism" to apply to subtype polymorphism is akin to using "football" to apply to two very different games.

Comment: I agree. But "football" *is* used to tag multiple ball games. English is like that. and "polymorphism" is similarly used.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: Sure, I was bit obtuse in what I meant. I think it's important to note that the use of "polymorphism" has two very different meanings in programming.

Comment: I don't think anyone uses just "polymorphism" where template programming is concerned. It always tends to be specified as "compile-time polymorphism" - by which it is meant "achieves sort of same thing as polymorphism, except at compile-time".