# Interface Early/Late Binding in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, interface, binding, clr

In Wagner's "[Effective C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321658701)," item 23, he explains that

> interface methods are not
>   virtual...they are a declaration of a
>   concrete implementation.

I find that to be a conundrum, because it means that interface methods represent early binding, and yet they have the behavior of late-binding.  It rouses curiosity of how they work under the covers.  In C++ this would turn into a discussion of vtables.  In C#, I don't know what it turns into.  Can someone spell it out?

p.s. This question has [a cousin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484214/c-early-and-late-binding), but this question focuses on interfaces.
p.p.s. Please don't worry about "you don't need to know how it works."  Again, this is about curiosity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right, they are not virtual from the language point of view.  But they actually are as far as the CLR is concerned.  This sample code:

```
class Example : IDisposable {
    public void Dispose() {}
}
```

Produces this IL for the Dispose() method:

```
.method public hidebysig newslot virtual final    // <=== here
        instance void  Dispose() cil managed
{
  // Unimportant
} // end of method Example::Dispose
```

Note the attributes on the method: *virtual* and *final*.  The final is what ensures that you can't override the method in a derived class.  Making the interface method implementation behave like a non-virtual method in the language but a virtual one at runtime.

This then also answers your question about early/late binding.  It's early, the v-table slot is filled in when the class is loaded.

Comment: Clearly your post is my answer.  There is just one detail.  You say an interface represents early binding, but it certainly exhibits late binding: `foreach(IMyInterface foo in Yahoo) foo.Run();`.  In this case, determining which `Run` method to call must occur well-after the class is loaded, yes?  How is that not late-binding?

Comment: @Brent Arias - It depends on your definition of "late binding". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842102/c-polymorphism/3842173#3842173

Comment: No, that's early bound.  The call can be made without having to search through a list of possible candidate methods.  Late binding has a well defined meaning, in C# it involves the *dynamic* keyword or System.Reflection.  Key point about interface method calls is that they are *always* indirect calls (callvirt), never a direct call.  Even though the language says that they are not virtual.  (I'll avoid mentioning that C# uses callvirt even on non-virtual methods to get the cheap null check).