# Calling implementation of abstract method

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm studying on abstract methods and abstract classes. I don't understand how the following code runs without a compiler error and prints `stackoverflow`. I expected that error because I don't understand how it knows to call `Playput`'s `chew()` method. Could you explain?

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/U2jDVP)

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        new Platypus();
    }
}

abstract class Mammal 
{ 
    abstract public String chew(); 
    public Mammal() 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(chew()); // Does this line compile?
    }
}

class Platypus : Mammal 
{ 
    override public String chew() 
    { 
        return "stackoverflow"; 
    }  
}
```

Comment: This may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842102/c-sharp-polymorphism

Comment: @Fildor I wouldn't want to change the author's code.

Comment: This kind of functionality is usually implemented by generating a virtual method table https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table

Comment: Ah, so the comment is in the original code, that you are studying ... I see.

Comment: @Fildor yes, thank you. If you can explain how it compiles and prints it in detail, I really appreciate.

Comment: I think, Guru's answer pretty much explains it. Just be aware, that this is not a good idea, however. The reason for that is also in that answer.

Answer (score 3):

`Mammal` is an abstract class, i.e. can not be instantiated. `abstract public String chew();` means that any concrete (i.e. non-abstract) inheritor should have `chew` implemented so when any instance of concrete `Mammal` inheritor is created it has callable `chew` method which can be called during construction (underlying mechanism is basically the same as with "ordinary" polymorphism via `virtual`-`override`).

Note that some static analysis tools will give you warning like ["Virtual member call in a constructor"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/119543/18910197) due to possibly of unexpected behavior due  to the order of member [initializations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/VirtualMemberCallInConstructor.html).

Related (including ones from the comments):

1. [Docs about C# polymorphism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/object-oriented/polymorphism)
2. [SO on C# polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842102/c-sharp-polymorphism)
3. [Virtual method table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)