# Name-hiding static member functions in C++: good practice?

Tags: c++, inheritance

In my time as a C++ programmer, I've typically thought that name-hiding should be avoided because it can lead to confusion. For example, if you have a base class with a function f() and a derived class with a function f(), and f() is not virtual, a caller might accidentally call the wrong f().

However, I ran into an example while reading Herb Sutter's Exceptional C++ book where a case of name hiding seems to be encouraged. To make a case-insensitive string, he suggests that we make a case-insensitive version of `std::basic_string<>` by creating a `char_traits` class that inherits from `char_traits<char>` (which is a non-polymorphic static class) like so:

```
struct ci_char_traits : public char_traits<char>
{
  static bool eq( char c1, char c2 ) { /*...*/ }
  static bool lt( char c1, char c2 ) { /*...*/ }
  static int compare( const char* s1,
                      const char* s2,
                      size_t n)       { /*...*/ }
  static const char*
  find( const char* s, int n, char a ) { /*...*/ }
}
```

(I left out the function definitions to make it more concise). Essentially, we are inheriting all of the functions of `char_traits<char>`, and we are hiding the ones that we want to modify in order to make it case-insensitive. Then, you define the case insensitive string like so:

```
typedef basic_string<char, ci_char_traits> ci_string;
```

Now I do think this is a pretty neat trick! But I wonder if this kind of thing is considered 'good practice' because name-hiding is typically frowned upon. Perhaps it is more acceptable to name-hide static member functions than other types of functions?

Comment: The alternative is to implement `ci_char_traits` from scratch, which would instead lead to code duplication.

Comment: Technically you could also forward to a private member. But this allows the Empty Base Class Optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference here is that the traits class is not polymorphic, so there will never be any confusion as to which interface is used.

`ci_char_traits` could of course be implemented with private inheritance, encapsulation or simply deferring to `std::char_traits<>`. All of these approaches would require more maintenance.

#### Update:

There has been some discussion in the comments on whether templates are polymorphic. I will elaborate.

The construct `std::basic_string<char, ci_char_traits>` causes template expansion of the template `std::basic_string<class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator>`. During this expansion, the following type substitutions are made:

- `CharT` is replaced with `char`
- `Traits` is replaced with `ci_char_traits`
- `Allocator` is replaced with `std::allocator<char>`

Therefore, the class generated by the compiler is:

`std::basic_string<char, ci_char_traits, std::allocator<char>>`

This is not a polymorphic class.

This class will have a member typedef called `std::basic_string<char, ci_char_traits, std::allocator<char>>::traits_type`, which will unequivocally be the type `ci_char_traits`.

Therefore, this template expansion will result in a non-polymorphic class which uses the non-polymorphic class `ci_char_traits` to determine the behaviour of character-based operations such as comparison.

Which overload of `eq` and `lt` will be called by code in class `std::basic_string<char, ci_char_traits, std::allocator<char>>` is precisely defined, which is why in this case, it is not bad practice to overload these static member functions.

Comment: it's not _runtime_ polymorphic. It is compile time polymorphic. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128838/compile-time-polymorphism-and-runtime-polymorphism

Comment: @MooingDuck In my view "compile time polymorphism" is an oxymoron. There is no "poly" about it. The compiler selects the specify type you specify in the template argument list of `std::string<>`.

Comment: There's plenty of "poly" about it. You can pass in any type that fits the bill.

Comment: @StoryTeller Templates are not code. They are a code-writing service. One template can produce an infinite set of classes. This could be construed as "poly". But the second part of the word is "morph" which means "change". Once the template expansion has written our class, it's fixed. Therefore not "polymorphic". There's probably a word, but "polymorphism" is the wrong one, and it gives beginners the wrong idea, as evidenced by the question.

Comment: Are you going to shift the goal post now? A template "morphs" to a new function with each type it is given. That's a perfectly valid use of both terms. Polymorphism is appropriate, and the "static" indicates when it happens.

Comment: @StoryTeller nope, a template writes code. Nothing more.

Comment: You are perfectly within the right to hold this idiosyncratic view. Just bear in mind that saying that "a template writes code. Nothing more" is an even bigger disservice to novices.

Comment: Given that templates are Turing Complete, I find it strange to not consider them code. They may produce code, but I don't see that as an objection to them being code too.

Comment: @MSalters Turing complete is one thing, code is another. You couldn’t write for example, a program that runs a continuous loop such as a game of space invaders using merely template expansion. You’d need to actually produce code that executed on a processor. Turing complete merely means that it is provable that a given sequence of instructions will find a stopping state.

Comment: @RichardHodges: Turing complete means a different thing.

Comment: @geza you're right. A machine is Turing complete if it can emulate any other Turing machine. In that sense, templates are theoretically Turning complete. However, being Turing Complete does not imply polymorphism. Polymorphism is (essentially) the ability for code to conditionally execute against varying inputs. The inputs to a template expansion do not vary during any one 'run'. Polymorphism requires that a computer system respond to varying (or variable) inputs at runtime. Template expansions do not do that.

Comment: @RichardHodges: I don't really want to argue about what polymorphism really is :) For someone, it means runtime polymorpism only, for others it could mean compile-time as well. If someone just says "polymorphism" in a C++ context, I'd assume runtime polymorphism. But, for me, polymorphism could mean compile-time polymorphism as well. A template (a function too) can behave differently depending on their arguments, so I'd consider this as (compile-time) polymorphism as well. (and I think that turing completeness doesn't have to do anything about this)

Comment: @geza by this logic, any program with an "if" statement in it would be polymorphic. Anyway. If my answer is factual and helps the OP to understand why Herb deems it ok to overload these methods, please upvote it. If you think my answer can be improved, please let me know (or edit it), and if you believe it is factually incorrect (more than just a minor disagreement over terms), by all means downvote it and explain the problem.

Comment: @RichardHodges: I'd say that the implementation of `ci_char_traits` is fine, because it is used in a very special way, where it cannot cause any problems, misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0):

In the case-insensitive example it is more a matter of implementing an interface, it just happens that because this interface is done via templates that it is a compile-time matter rather than run-time.

To implement std::char_traits you simply cannot use different names (at least without a great deal of mucking with basic_string instead), those names are part of the interface.